# Is it correct to call std::move on an exception object?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, raii

I am interested to know if is it correct to move an exception object to some local variable. Is there any possibility for this action to lead into UB? My concerrns are due to the fact that catching by reference  assumes access to exception object, which is located in other place (because it must live until the end of the stack unwinding). See example below.

```
int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> res; //may be heavy object, it's only example
    int a[3][5];// assume filled
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                if(a[i][j] % 2 ==0 )
                {
                    throw std::pair<int,int>(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(std::pair<int,int>& pair)
    {
        res = std::move(pair);
    }
}
```

Comment: a `pair<int,int>` would still be copied anyway.

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be "heavy" objects.

Comment: Moving an exception object is fine: the result needs to be destructible anyway and you wouldn't care about the state of the object  in most cases. Of course, if you plan to rethrow the exception it would have changed its state to some indeterminate one (although, in case of `std::pair<int, int>` moving the object won't affect the original - it will always be copied).

Comment: Although I don't see any advantage, I don't think there would be a problem. A little side note: exceptions shouldn't be thrown in the normal execution flow but just for rare, exceptional events.

Comment: Since C++11, the standard way to capture an exception object and extend its life beyond the `catch` block is to use [`std::current_exception()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception), but I don't see any way to access the object it captures, you can only re-throw it with [`std::rethrow_exception()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception).

Comment: The question is not which practice is better, and it doesn't make sense which concrete type of exception. The question is still about behavior of programm.

Answer (score 2):

Moved-out object is still in a valid state.

Even if you rethrow the exception via `throw;`, and catch it again, it will work.

The result might be unexpected for an object left in a valid-but-unspecified state (assuming you use such an object instead of a pair of ints), but still no UB.

Answer (score 0):

As your code does not follows good practice by throwing an exception for an expected result, it really does not matter much the answer of the question as your should rewrite your code anyway...

Here is an example on how you could write such code.

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, int> find(int(&a)[3][5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                return std::pair<int, int>(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    return {};
}

int main()
{
    int a[3][5];// assume filled
    auto res = find(a);
}
```

While your initial code would works, throwing and catching exception could be slow thus even with moving, your code might be slower that a version that do not use exception to return the result.

**A good practice** is to use exception only for unexpected errors.